# Why does header button onPress act differently than regular button onPress?

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, onpress

I have a method called sendResults() that makes an API call and does some array manipulation. When I call the method using a "normal" TouchableOpacity button, everything works fine. However, when I call it using a button I have placed in the App Stack header, the method does not run correctly. It feels like an async issue (?) but not sure...

Here is the code for the two buttons.

```js
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        sendResults(); // works fine
      }}
      style={styles.buttonStyle}
    >
      <Text>Save</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            sendResults(); // doesn't work
          }}
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
        >
          <Text>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  }, []);
```

**Edit: sendResults() code**

```js
  // Shows alert confirming user wants to send results to API
  const sendResults = () => {
    Alert.alert("Save Results", "Alert", [
      {
        text: "Save & Quit",
        onPress: () => postNumsAndNavigate(),
        style: "destructive",
      },
      { text: "Cancel", onPress: () => console.log("") },
    ]);
  };

  // Save Results button
  const postNumsAndNavigate = async () => {
    if (bibNums.length == 0) {
      alert("You have not recorded any results. Please try again.");
    } else if (bibNums.filter((entry) => entry == "").length > 0) {
      alert("Blank");
    } else {
      console.log("\n" + bibNums);
      await postNums();
      AsyncStorage.setItem(`done`, "true");
      navigation.navigate("Home Screen");
    }
  };
```

postNums() does an API call.

**Edit 2: bibNums declaration**

const [bibNums, setBibNums] = useState([]);

Comment: could you elaborate on the `does not run correctly` part? what are your findings so far?

Comment: @diedu I added the code of sendResults(). the console.log in postNumsAndNavigate() should return an array of numbers (which it does in the one case). In the case where it does not run correctly, it only returns the first number.

Comment: Where does the `bibNums` variable come from? are you referring to that variable when you say it has an incorrect value?

Comment: @diedu I added the bibNums declaration above. It is changed in various functions (added to and removed from) until the user taps the button. At that point, it is sent to the API in postNums().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the handler of the navigation button only once because your useEffect doesn't have any dependency; it runs only when the component is mounted, it captures an old reference of `sendResults`. `sendResults` changes every time `postNumsAndNavigate` and `bibNums` change. Add `sendResults` to the dependency array to update the navigation button handler every time `sendResults` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
...
}, [sendResults])
```

It works correctly for the `TouchableOpacity` because you are assigning the handler on every render.

`onPress={() => {sendResults()}}`

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't working. I changed the empty brackets to [sendResults], and it still only returns the first number.
Example: Array ["12", "57", "84"]. Correct button returns 12, 57, 84. Incorrect button returns 12.

Comment: @aequinox  could you add details to your question about where each piece of code is located? is that a single component? if they are separated into different components could you explain how the component tree looks like

Comment: they are in a single component. The button that is working is inside the main return(). Everything else I've shown is just inside the component. Let me know if I'm understanding you correctly / can give any more information.

Comment: @aequinox I don't think it would be possible but, is the `sendResults` declaration after the `useEffect`? could you console.log(bibNums) in your `useEffect` before `navigation.setOptions(` to check what is its value before you press the header button

Comment: That was the issue -- thank you! Why does that matter?